# Textbox not accepting UTF8

Tags: powerbi

How to use universal standard UTF8 on final dashboard layout (not datasets but titles and layout)?

Specifically the *textbox*  component is not accepting copy/paste of UTF-8 characters as *«this»* or "→".

PS: my windows locale is wrong and enforce the use of Windows-1252 charset... but I **must to use UTF-8** on my Power BI dashboards.

Comment: Windows GUI works with Unicode (i.e. UTF-16) not with UTF-8.

Comment: Hi @i486, seems not a Windows GUI problem, but a *textbox* restriction (seems only ASCII is valid)... About UTF-8, [it is near universal adoption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Adoption)...  And it is the occidental standard, Microsoft software MUST export/import UTF8 in occidental  countries like Brazil.

Comment: I am not familiar with Power BI but if we talk about standard textbox control, it works with ANSI (ASCII, not UTF-8) and Unicode (i.e. UTF-16).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to copy-paste in those characters into a Textbox with no dramas - see below:

[image: textbox with desired results]

My Windows display language and Keyboard are both: English (Australia).

Perhaps you need to turn on the Preview feature: Smart narrative visual?  That changes the Textbox UX a lot.

[image]